# ASP.NET MVC 2 Post AJAX from from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms, asp.net-ajax

I got control with strongly typed View, with Ajax.BeginForm(). Now I would like to change submit method from

```
<input type="submit" id="testClick" value="Submit" />
```

To some javascript method DoSubmit().
What I tried is :

- Invoke click on that submit button
- Invoke submit on form  ('form1').submit(), document.forms['form1'].submit()
- jQuery forms with ('form1').AjaxSubmit();
- Create jQuery AJAX

  ```
  $.ajax({                                                        
      type: "POST",
      url: $("#form1").attr("action"),
      data: $("#form1").serialize(),            
      success: function() {
          alert("epic win!!!1!1!")      
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("epic fail!")                                        
      }
  });
  ```

All those method created normal request (not AJAX), or they didn't work. So anyone know how I can do AJAX submit "Form", from JavaScript and strongly typed mechanism (public AcrionResult MyFormAction(FormModel model); ) will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this work fine for me using the forms plugin for jquery. What I found tho, was that I had to handle the click event, do the ajax submit and then return false to ensure that the normal post didn't occur.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#testClick').click(function(){
        $('#form1').ajaxSubmit();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer it work fine. But there is one problem after that ajax submit form isn't validate. I'm using Xval and jquery.validation. 
I tried to run  :
 $('#form1').validate(); 
after ajaxSubmit or before and it didn't work